# $m = r\sqrt\frac{x}{a}$. Make $x$ the subject of the formula.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Make $x$ the subject of the formula 
>   $$m = r\sqrt\frac{x}{a}$$

I don't know how to approach this question. Thank you and help is appreciated

Comment: You are being asked to isolate $x$. Your answer should be in the form $$x= \text{some expression involving m, r, and a}$$

Comment: What is $X$? The question is unclear.

Comment: Why don't you know how to approach it? And, this has nothing to do with linear algebra.

Answer (score 1):

The question is asking you to solve for $x$ in terms of everything else ($x=\cdots$).  You can do so by *reversing* the operations you are performing onto $x$.

> \begin{align}m&=r\sqrt{\frac{x}{a}}\\\frac{m}{r}&=\sqrt{\frac{x}{a}}\\\bigg(\frac{m}{r}\bigg)^2&=\frac{x}{a}\\a\bigg(\frac{m}{r}\bigg)^2&=x\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The basic concept in any "make $x$ the subject" or "solve for $x$" is "undo" whatever has been done to $x$. That is what Andrew Chin did!

Here, we have $m= r\sqrt{\frac{x}{a}}$.  If you were given $x$ and asked to find $m$ you would

1) Divide $x$ by $a$.

2) Take the square root.

3) Multiply by $r$.

To "undo" that, do the opposite (inverse) of each step in the opposite order.

To undo "multiply by $r$", divide by r (and, of course, do that on both sides of the equation).  That gives $\frac{m}{r}= \sqrt{\frac{x}{a}}$.

To undo "take the square root", square.  That gives $\left(\frac{m}{r}\right)= \frac{m^2}{r^2}= \frac{x}{a}$.

To undo "divide by $a$", multiply by $a$.  That gives $\frac{am^2}{r^2}= x$.